# Downloading Financial Statements in R with finstr

Tags: r

I'm trying to download financial statements in R using a package at: 
[Financial statements in R](https://github.com/bergant/finstr)

I'm trying to modify the example in their read me for other companies. I have tried to download the last two Tesla Q's.

The code I modified so far is:

```
 xbrl_url2017Q3 <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459018026353/tsla-20180930.xml"
 xbrl_url2017Q2 <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459018019254/tsla-20180630.xml"
 old_o <- options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 xbrl_data_tsla2017Q3 <- xbrlDoAll(xbrl_url2017Q3)
```

**Error from the line above is:**

Error in fileFromCache(file) : 
  Error in download.file(file, cached.file, quiet = !verbose) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459018026353/https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2018/dei-2018-01-31.xsd'

In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(file, cached.file, quiet = !verbose) :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459018026353/https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2018/dei-2018-01-31.xsd': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

```
 xbrl_data_tsla2017Q2 <- xbrlDoAll(xbrl_url2017Q2)
 options(old_o)

 tsla2017Q3 <- xbrl_get_statements(xbrl_data_tsla2017Q3)
 tsla2017Q2 <- xbrl_get_statements(xbrl_data_tsla2017Q2 )
 tsla2017Q2

balance_sheet2017Q2 <- tsla2017Q2$StatementOfFinancialPositionClassified
balance_sheet2017Q3<- tsla2017Q3$StatementOfFinancialPositionClassified
income2017Q2 <- tsla2017Q2$StatementOfIncome
income2017Q3 <- tsla2017Q3$StatementOfIncome
balance_sheet2017Q3
```

Returns "NULL"

See the 10-Q at tesla's [SEC fillings](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001318605&owner=exclude&count=40&hidefilings=0).

[The last 10-Q.](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459018026353/0001564590-18-026353-index.htm)

Any recommendations on how I can go about this?

I'm looking to download the financial data to play around it with and would like it in tidy formate.

Comment: *I have tried to download the last two Tesla Q's.* ... And what happened? Please describe the problem. Errors? Undesired results?

Comment: in your `xbrl_get_statements` you are referencing aapl not tsla, `xbrl_data_aapl2013`; this object is not defined and is a leftover of your copy and pasting from the package vignette. You need xbrl_data_tsla2017Q3 in this field. Fix this first and see if you still have an error.

Comment: I updated my code to show where I get the errors. Maybe It's the link I use to the file.  I'm also open to other packages if anyone else knows. Currently playing around in python to see if I can solve that issue there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem with the XBRL package where not all XML schemas are downloaded in the cache for some SEC filings. [Download the missing schema](https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2018/dei-2018-01-31.xsd) in your cache folder and retry the `xbrlDoAll` call - it should work this time.

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t understand about schemas, and this solved my problem. It would have helped even more if you explained that I had to go one by one on the sec website, download the missing xsd file, remove the .htm subscript and put in the cache. If there is an easier way to update all schemes, that would have really been amazing, but I didn’t figure that out. Gave you +1

Comment: Hi David, could you please explain how did you fix this issue? How did you download the .htm? And in which cache folder to save the .xsd?

Comment: @DavidLucey, I'd also be interested to hear more about your process, esp. relating to removing the .htm subscript. I'm not seeing that in the contents of the .xsd file. I've been saving the relevant .xsd files R tells me are missing in the cache folder in my working directory, but my cache folder is deleted after using a finreportr function and I need to download the missing .xsd files again.

Comment: I wrote this post https://redwallanalytics.com/2020/02/18/a-walk-though-of-accessing-financial-statements-with-xbrl-in-r-part-1/ and there is a lot on this subject in the comments